# <Div> Not displaying before a sleep method

Tags: javascript, html

I have a

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <font size="6">
                    <p>Message Text</p>
                </font>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i'm trying to get this message to appear after a button is clicked then sleep for 2-3 seconds then keep going on the code, but what i'm getting is sleep 2-3 seconds then display the message and my page reloads as i have it set up.

On my button click event:

```
$("#ButtonID").click()
{
 if (validate stuff) {//code here}
 else {modal.style.display = "block"; sleep(3);}
}
```

Sleep Function i grabbed from somewhere in stackoverflow

```
function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

What i want here is that when i click the button the div displays and then it waits 3 seconds before it keeps the code as it does a post of data then returns to the same page, as what i get here is sleep 3 seconds, display the div and then it refreshes my page almost instantly which leaves no time to see the message as intended.

Comment: You're blocking the browser thread for 3 seconds, so it can't *draw the updates* until that's done.  Don't block the browser thread like that.  If you want something to happen 3 seconds later, use `setTimeout()` to schedule it to happen 3 seconds later.  Never block the thread.

Comment: @David well what i want here is just wait 3 seconds AFTER the block is displayed and i've been looking for a few hours now, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the browser thread for 3 seconds, so it can't *draw the updates* until that's done.

The simple rule is: **Never block the browser thread**.

Any time you find yourself with something like this:

```
doSomething();
wait3Seconds();
doSomethingElse();
```

What you *really want* is this:

```
doSomething();
setTimeout(doSomethingElse, 3000);
```

That is, schedule the code to run after 3 seconds instead of trying to block *everything* for 3 seconds.  Blocking is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done using setTimeout

```
$("#ButtonID").click(function()
{
     setTimeout(function() {
       if (validate stuff) {//code here}
       else {modal.style.display = "block";}
     }, 3000);
});
```